# ruby watir, could not init watir when running at server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

Watir Version: (6.1.0)

Selenium Version: selenium-webdriver (3.0.5)

In code I call init:

```
Watir::Browser.new :chrome
```

It running in minute and return :

```
Timeout::Error (Rails Rack application timed out during
```

But I call that in rails console, That work.

Comment: Chrome is default in WATIR, you don't have to pass argument as `:chrome`

Comment: Why are you running these old versions of Watir and Selenium? Often Timeout errors are caused by a browser / webdriver / selenium version mismatch. I'd recommend getting everything up-to date.

Comment: What is the full text of the error?

Comment: It just through timeout error. I added gem 'headless' and call it before waitir. I think It still can not init

Comment: How are you executing this? You shouldn't be executing this in the context of a Rails console. Use a test runner like RSpec or MiniTest to kick off your code against your Rails app.